# node.js return function value inside setinterval

Tags: node.js, function, setinterval

I was called function inside setinterval. But i don't take return value from function.

My code:

```
function getApiData() {
    request({
        url : 'http://testest.com',
        json : true
    }, (error, response , body) => {
      if(!error && response.statusCode == 200){
        return JSON.stringify(body); 
      }
      else{
        return undefined;
      } 
    });
}
```

Call:

```
setInterval(() => {

    var data = getApiData();
    console.log(data);

    }, 2000);
```

Output : `Undefined`

Please help me. (I am learning new)

Comment: The value is undefined because the function `getApiData` doesn't return a value. There is no return statement.

Comment: `(error, response , body) => { ...` is a separate function that returns parsed JSON/undefined. And since it is passed as a callback to `request(...` there is no way to access the returned value of this callback. You have to handle the data within this callback. If you are still unclear, take a look at the docs for `request(...` to see how it is used.

Comment: thank u. I guess I should look for more.

Comment: `(error, response , body) => {
      if(!error && response.statusCode == 200){
        return JSON.stringify(body); 
      }` add `console.log(error)` in that block and you will know what's the error. Now there's an error and as per your definition, it is returning undefined, as specified

Answer (score 0):

As @Aravindan Ve pointed out, there is no way to get retrieve the value returned by that function.So, define a different function

```
functionPrintResponse(res){
 console.log(res)
}
```

and instead of returning there, invoke `functionPrintResponse(JSON.stringify(body))`